# Pyspark not like operator for array

Tags: pyspark

I have a list of fast food chains (over 300 rows). In my data, the name of each fast food chain could be `McDonald's, Mcdonald's 100, etc.` I cant test for exact equality because then I'd be missing Mcdonald's 100 for example. I want to test and see if each fast food chains appears in my table in any place in my column.

Dataframe:

```
ID Name
1 Mcdonad's
2 Mcdonald's 100
3 Subway 600
```

Restaurant list:

```
["Mcdonald's", "Subway", etc.]
```

How can I exclude everything in my dataframe that doesn't include the restaurants in the restaurant list?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-isin-is-not-in-operator-example/

Comment: @LiamFiddler This tests for exact operation. It wouldn't  pick all the different variations

Comment: Are the added characters always numeric? If so, you could simply filter out non-alpha characters and then utilize the above.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it can be something like  `Mcdonald's S1` or it could be `S1 Mcdonald's`

Comment: Ok, so here's my over-engineered solution I built for a similar project where misspellings could come in a variety of forms and there was no consistency, meaning a new misspelling could pop up at any time. I constructed a list of standard spellings, then used CountVectorization and cosine similarity to determine which standard spelling was closest to the misspelt name, and corrected based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html) to check if one string matches a part of another. That will not cover typos like `Mcdonad's` but it will handle leading and trailing symbols. For fuzzy matching you can look at [levenshtein](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.levenshtein.html) distance.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


fast_food_chains = ["Mcdonald's", "Subway", ]

# create pyspark df from list
df_chains = spark \
    .createDataFrame(fast_food_chains, StringType()) \
    .withColumnRenamed('value', 'chain_name')

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "Mcdonad's"),
        (2, "Mcdonald's 100"),
        (3, "Subway 600")

    ],
    ["id", "chain_name"]
)

# join dfs using contains
df \
    .join(df_chains, df.chain_name.contains(df_chains.chain_name)) \
    .show()
+---+--------------+----------+
| id|    chain_name|chain_name|
+---+--------------+----------+
|  2|Mcdonald's 100|Mcdonald's|
|  3|    Subway 600|    Subway|
+---+--------------+----------+
```